# SQL - I have a 'People' table and an 'Account' table. How do I list all of the people in rows, and have a balance column for each account type?

Tags: sql, case, intersystems-cache

I was having a hard time figuring out how to title this question, so my apologies in advance.

Here is my my situation:

I have one table that has just people in it. I have another table that has all the accounts, with a personID, accountType, and balance column. A person can have multiple accounts, there are different account types, and not everyone has all of the different account types.

How can I write a query where I list one person per row, and have a column for the balance of each "account type"?

Ideally, my query would look something like this:

```
PersonID | Account Type 1 Bal | Account Type 2 Bal | Account Type 3 Bal |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1    |         $100       |         null       |         null       |
    2    |         null       |         $12        |         $1300      |
    3    |         null       |         null       |         $5         |
    4    |         $150       |         null       |         null       |
    5    |         $65        |         $300       |         $45        |
```

I would assume I would use some sort of case statement, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet. Also, if they have multiple of the same account type, i assume I would just use sum() correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Intersystems Cache. My apologies, I'll update the question

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for `postgres`

```
select p.person_id,
  (select sum(a.balance) from account a where a.person_id = p.person_id and a.account_type = 'Type1') type1_balance,
  (select sum(a.balance) from account a where a.person_id = p.person_id and a.account_type = 'Type2') type2_balance,
  (select sum(a.balance) from account a where a.person_id = p.person_id and a.account_type = 'Type3') type3_balance
from person p
```

[sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0b713/1)

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps -

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30ebb/10/0

```
CREATE TABLE person
    ("person_id" int, "name" varchar2(9))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO person ("person_id", "name")
         VALUES (1, '''Abcd''')
    INTO person ("person_id", "name")
         VALUES (2, '''xyz''')
    INTO person ("person_id", "name")
         VALUES (3, '''jjjjj''')
    INTO person ("person_id", "name")
         VALUES (4, '''sfds''')
    INTO person ("person_id", "name")
         VALUES (5, '''temp''')
SELECT * FROM dual
;

CREATE TABLE accounts
    ("personID" int, "accountType" int, "balance" int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO accounts ("personID", "accountType", "balance")
         VALUES (1, 1, 100)
    INTO accounts ("personID", "accountType", "balance")
         VALUES (1, 2, 150)
    INTO accounts ("personID", "accountType", "balance")
         VALUES (2, 1, 20)
    INTO accounts ("personID", "accountType", "balance")
         VALUES (3, 1, 40)
    INTO accounts ("personID", "accountType", "balance")
         VALUES (3, 2, 440)
    INTO accounts ("personID", "accountType", "balance")
         VALUES (4, 1, 600)
    INTO accounts ("personID", "accountType", "balance")
         VALUES (5, 1, 43)
    INTO accounts ("personID", "accountType", "balance")
         VALUES (5, 2, 50)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

> Query -

```
select * from (
select p."person_id", a."accountType", a."balance"
from person p, accounts a
where p."person_id" = a."personID"
)
pivot (sum("balance") for "accountType" in (1 as acc_type1_bal,2 as acc_type2_bal));


person_id   ACC_TYPE1_BAL   ACC_TYPE2_BAL
1   100 150
2   20  (null)
4   600 (null)
5   43  50
3   40  440
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select personid
      ,sum(ac1bal) accounttype1bal
      ,sum(ac2bal) accounttype2bal
      ,sum(ac3bal) accounttype3bal
from (
select persontable.personid
        ,case when (accounttype=1) then bal end ac1bal
        ,case when (accounttype=2) then bal end ac2bal
        ,case when (accounttype=3) then bal end ac3bal
from persontable
left join accounttable on persontable.personid = accounttable.personid
    )
group by personid
```